# How do I change the 'About' screen of Mac OS X in a Java program?

Tags: java, macos

Mac OS X features an 'About' screen for applications.

[image]

[image: Defualt About screen]

But how do I change the version number that is displayed, the icon shown, and add some text programmatically? I don't want a seperate Mac application bundle trough, I want to keep anything in a single multiplatform Jar file. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do this is the application bundle. Mac-OS speficic behavior and platform independent code is a conflicting requirement...

Comment: The dock icon can be set programmatically. The application name can be set programmatically. The about screen contents can't? :(

Comment: The about screen is not generated by Java I believe, but the executable that launches java. I guess the application name is derived from the Frame and by dock you mean something like a Trayicon using Desktop API? Those are under Java's control obviously.

Comment: I have set the dock icon with `Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(icon);` (`icon` is a java.awt.Image created some earlier in the code) and the application name was set by `System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Alfabet");`

Comment: I found [this article](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-mac-osx-about-preferences-quit-application-adapter) which might be helpful

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to change the contents of the default About dialog, but you can just implement a handleAbout that shows whatever About dialog you want to create in Java. That also allows you to have an About dialog that's the same on all platforms. (And now I see that Robin linked an article showing you exactly how to do it, so +1.)

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this was to use [OSXAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/legacy/mac/library/samplecode/OSXAdapter) and call its `setAboutHandler(...)` method pointing to your method for popping up an about dialog. But apparently that's legacy now.

Comment: Thanks, but your link is broken.

Comment: Really? It works for me. (Expands to different URL, though: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/legacy/mac/library/samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Sorry, the link didn't work because I was on my iPad. On my mac the link works. Thank you :)

Comment: Good for you @comBoy! Note that the code that I linked to uses the same `com.apple.eawt` classes as mentioned in @Robin's solution, but it does this reflectively so your code doesn't have to import those classes. Makes it easier to have platform independent code.